# How to rescale and save image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, pixel, rescale

I am reading an 'MHD' file which it's giving me info like below:

```
Filename: 'patient0001_2CH_ED_gt.mhd'
             Format: 'MHA'
     CompressedData: 'false'
         ObjectType: 'image'
 NumberOfDimensions: 3
         BinaryData: 'true'
          ByteOrder: 'false'
    TransformMatrix: [1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1]
   CenterOfRotation: [0 0 0]
 AnatomicalOrientation: 'RAI'
             Offset: [0 0 0]
    PixelDimensions: [0.3080 0.1540 1.5400]
         Dimensions: [549 778 1]
ElementNumberOfChannels: '1'
           DataType: 'uchar'
           DataFile: 'patient0001_2CH_ED_gt.raw'
           BitDepth: 8
         HeaderSize: 384
```

Then by another function, I will read the info, then produce the image. Then, I need to rescale image dimension with `pixel dimension ( PixelDimensions: [0.3080 0.1540 1.5400])`, and I used `imagesc` in order to do this like below code, but it changes the unique value of my image.

Is there any way to rescale the image without `imagesc`? also `imagesc` produces 3 channels which I don't want, and apparently, all channels are the same.

```
rows = 1:info.Dimensions(1);
cols = 1:info.Dimensions(2);
Im2 = imagesc(rows.*info.PixelDimensions(1),cols.*info.PixelDimensions(2),Im(:,:)');
saveas(gcf,'Output_filename.png')
```

Comment: [`imresize`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html)?

Comment: @beaker how can I used imresize to rescale the Im(:,:) to info.PixelDimensions(1), info.PixelDimensions(2)? is there any example?